# numerical integration with c

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I have to do numerical integration for a set of data points from a text file.

my data points look like

```
0.5   0.479425539
1     0.841470985
1.5   0.997494987
2     0.909297427
2.5   0.598472144
3     0.141120008
3.5   -0.350783228
4     -0.756802495
4.5   -0.977530118
5     -0.958924275
```

my attempt is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

double trapezoidalRule (double size, double *x, double *y)
{
    double sum = 0.0,increment;
    int k;
    for (k=1; k<size; k++)
    {
        increment = 0.5 * (x[k]-x[k-1]) * (y[k]+y[k-1]);
        sum += increment;
    }
    return sum;
    _getch();
}
int main ( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char*  fileName = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "C:\\Users\\g\\Desktop\\test.txt";
    FILE*  inputFile = fopen (fileName, "r");
    int  k;
    double size,*x, *y;
    double integral;
    if ( inputFile ==NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Open failed for %s\n", fileName);
        exit(666); 
    }
    fscanf (inputFile, "%d", &size);
    printf (" Number of points: %d\n", size);

    x = (double *) calloc (size, sizeof(*x));
    y = (double *) calloc (size, sizeof(*y));

    for (k=0; k< size; k++)
        fscanf (inputFile, "%lg%lg" , x+k, y+k);
    integral = trapezoidalRule (size, x, y);
    printf ("Integral:", "\n", integral);
    printf ("\n");
    //printf ("check: ","\n", x[size-1], log(x[size-1]) );
    _getch();
}
```

but I am not getting the required output... I cant figure whats wrong... It shud compute the integral value, but its not... also the no of points is wrong...its just taking the first number, not counting the no of points... pls help...

Comment: why don't you start with a very trivial test input (e.g. 0 0; 1 1) where you know the result, and start debugging on that input.

Comment: Are you sure the `printf ("Integral:", "\n", integral);` line is correct? I don't see any _format specifiers_ in your _format_ parameter "Integral:".

Comment: That certainly isn't C++ code.

Comment: To start with, why tag this as C++ when there is no C++ code in there? Also, why use a `double` for the size (which leads to your problem with `size` as `fscanf` is told to read an _integer_).

Comment: Better use Simpsons' rule, it is much more accurate for equally spaced points. Where do the points come from? There are better methods, but they select the points themselves...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not that far from the solution. The formula at least looks fine.

Maybe the biggest mistake that you have in your code is that you are missing, in your data, the number of points to read. So you code probably reads "0.5" as the number of points. Then, the loop on k just goes for k=0 (then k=1>0.5), that probably why you have only one point. To make it work, I did the following changes:

- Add the number of points at the beginning of your data file.
- Change the type of size for `int size`
- Print the value of the integral `printf ("Integral: %lg \n", integral);`

That made it work for me.

(Big edit since it has been retaged as C instead of C++)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be reading a double value using `%d` instead use the format specifier `%lf`. Also I do not understand why `size` is double. It seems it can only be a non-negative integer so probably `unsigned` will do best here.